# runif with .Machine$double.xmax as boundaries

Tags: r, random, precision, uniform-distribution

I wanted to generate a random real (I guess rational) number.

To do this I wanted to use `runif(1, min = m, max = M)` and my thoughts were to set `m; M` (absolute) as large as possible in order to make the interval as large as possible. Which brings me to my question:

```
M <- .Machine$double.xmax
m <- -M
runif(1, m, M)
## which returns
[1] Inf
```

Why is it not returning a number? Is the chosen interval simply too large?

**PS**

```
> .Machine$double.xmax
[1] 1.797693e+308
```

Comment: Interesting question. A workaround would be `M * runif(1, -1, 1)`.

Comment: Here is the source of `runif`: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/nmath/runif.c . It looks that `M` is the max double, wihle `M - (-M)` will be large than max double so `b - a` will be `Inf`, which might explain why `a + (b - a) * u` is `Inf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by mt1022 the reason is in `runif` [C source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/nmath/runif.c):

```
double runif(double a, double b)
{
    if (!R_FINITE(a) || !R_FINITE(b) || b < a)  ML_ERR_return_NAN;

    if (a == b)
    return a;
    else {
    double u;
    /* This is true of all builtin generators, but protect against
       user-supplied ones */
    do {u = unif_rand();} while (u <= 0 || u >= 1);
    return a + (b - a) * u;
    }
}
```

In the `return` argument you can see the formula `a + (b - a) * u` which transoform uniformly [0, 1] generated random value in the user supplied interval [a, b]. In your case it will be `-M + (M + M) * u`. So `M + M` in case it `1.79E308 + 1.79E308` generates `Inf`. I.e. `finite + Inf * finite = Inf`:

```
M + (M - m) * runif(1, 0, 1)
# Inf
```